# Why does stm32 use ICER=1 to disenable the interrupt instead of ISER=0?

Tags: stm32, cortex-m

My book teaches me to read *the guide to the cortex-m3* but i can not understand.

Comment: Could you provide a source / reference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The various register names are given in the reference manual for the particular part (eg: for STM32F4xx it is RM090).

The names are arbitrary and different for each peripheral but there are some patterns.  IER is often interrupt enable register, write 1 to enable the interrupt 0 to disable.  Something like ICR could be interrupt clear register.

For more details edit your question to specify which part you are using and which peripheral.